# Google scripts forms-How to fill a field automatically with fields from a google sheet

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

I have a html form in google scripts. Two fields of form are "worker name" and it´s "ID". When i am using the form, the names is are obtained from a google sheet that have 2 columns with worker name and ID information.

What i want to do is when i select a name, the field ID should be automatically filled with correspondent worker's ID.

The code that i have working is:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- Metro UI -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.korzh.com/metroui/v4/css/metro-all.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
        .container-small {
          max-width:800px;
          margin:0 auto;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body >

    <div class="container-small">
      <!-- content here -->
      <div class = "grid">
          <div class="cell-8 p-1">
              <div class="cell d-flex flex-row"><h3>Worker Medical Record</h3></div>
              <div class="cell flex-align-self-center"></div>
              
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="container-small">
      <!-- content here -->
      
      <div class="grid">
          <form id="epi-form" data-role="validator" action="javascript:" data-on-submit="addRecord">
            
            <div class="row">

              <div class="cell-4 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Data</label>
                  <input name="date" type="date" placeholder="Data" class="metro-input"data-validate="required date"/>
                </div>
              </div>
             
             <div class="cell-8 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Full Name</label>
                  <select data-role="select" name="name" data-validate="required not=''" >
                      <option  value="">disable selected></option>

                      <? for(const name of names)  { ?>
                      <option><?= name  ?></option>
                      <? } ?>
                      
                  </select>
                </div>
             </div>

              <div class="cell-6 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="id">Kennitala</label>
                  <input id="id" name="id" readonly type="number" class="metro-input"/>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="cell-6 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Project</label>
                  <select data-role="select" name="site" data-validate="required not=''">
                      <option disable selected></option>

                      <? for(const site of sites)  { ?>
                      <option><?= site  ?></option>
                      <? } ?>

                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>                        

              <div class="cell-12 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Description</label>
                  <textarea data-role="textarea" placeholder="Write here" data-auto-size="true" data-max-height="200" name="description" data-validate="required not=''"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="cell-4 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Issue Severity </label>
                  <select data-role="select" name="severity" data-validate="required not=''">
                    <option disable selected></option>
                    <option >None</option>
                    <option >Light</option>
                    <option >Average</option>
                    <option >Important</option>
                    <option >Critical</option>      
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="cell-4 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Work Related? </label>
                  <select data-role="select" name="workrelated" data-validate="required not=''">
                    <option disable selected></option>
                    <option >No</option>
                    <option >Yes</option>      
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="cell-4 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Cost</label>
                  <input name="value" type="currency" placeholder="kr" class="metro-input" min="0.01" max="100000"/>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="cell-4 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Sick Leave? </label>
                  <select data-role="select" name="sickleave" data-validate="required not=''">
                    <option disable selected></option>
                    <option >No</option>
                    <option >Yes</option>      
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="cell-4 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>From</label>
                  <input name="datesickin" type="date" placeholder="Data" class="metro-input"/>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="cell-4 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Until</label>
                  <input name="datesickout" type="date" placeholder="Data" class="metro-input"/>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="cell-12 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Notes</label>
                  <textarea data-role="textarea" placeholder="Write here" data-auto-size="true" data-max-height="200" name="notes"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

            
              <div class="cell-12 p-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="button success" id="collect-data">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>   
          </form>
            <div class="cell-12 p-1">
              <div class="form-group d-none" id="success-message"> <!-- Success Message -->
                  New Record Added!
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>

    <!-- Metro UI -->
    <script src="https://cdn.korzh.com/metroui/v4/js/metro.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Javascript to collect data -->
    <script>
      const epiForm = document.getElementById("epi-form")
      const successMessage = document.getElementById("success-message")
      const backToForm = document.getElementById("back-to-form")


      epiForm.addEventListener("submit",submitData)

      function submitData(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("Form Submitted")
        console.log(this)
      }
  //Function to add record and validate fields
      function addRecord(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => { 
          
          //Success case
            epiForm.reset() //reset
            const selectElements = epiForm.querySelectorAll("select") //reset select form
            selectElements.forEach(element => { //loop for each select
              const tempSelect = Metro.getPlugin(element,"select")
              tempSelect.val("")
            })

            //epiForm.classList.add("d-none") //submit and send success message
            
              document.getElementById("success-message").classList.remove("d-none")
              setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("success-message").classList.add("d-none")
              },2000)
              
                  
        }).withFailureHandler(() => {

        }).collectData(this)

      }

    backToForm.addEventListener("click",() => {
      epiForm.classList.remove("d-none") //submit and send success message
      successMessage.classList.add("d-none")
    })


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The code.gs is:

```
function doGet() {
  const htmlService = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index")
  htmlService.names = getNames_() // service to get values from list
  htmlService.sites = getSites_() // service to get values from list
  const html = htmlService.evaluate().addMetaTag("viewport","width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no")
  return html
}
```

Javacripts functions:

```
//Funtion to collect data from form to sheet

function collectData(formData){
 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15c_B9bfBQu1nJhh5o9wr67t2oUhsJdmDCiOpfUvzMwo")
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("DATA") //Sheet name to save
  const uniqueIds = ws.getRange( 2, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  
  var maxNum = 0;
  uniqueIds.forEach(r => {
    maxNum = r[0] > maxNum ? r[0] : maxNum
  });

  var newID = maxNum + 1;
  ws.appendRow([
                newID,
                formData.date,
                formData.name,
                formData.kennitala,
                formData.site,
                formData.description,
                formData.severity,
                formData.workrelated,
                formData.value,
                formData.sickleave,
                formData.datesickin,
                formData.datesickout, 
                formData.notes]) //fix values to google sheet rows
}

//Name Droplist Names
function getNames_(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15c_B9bfBQu1nJhh5o9wr67t2oUhsJdmDCiOpfUvzMwo")
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("WORKER_NAME") //Sheet name to get values
  const names = ws.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(r => r[0] !=="").map(r => r[0])
  return names
}

//Sites Droplist Sites
function getSites_(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15c_B9bfBQu1nJhh5o9wr67t2oUhsJdmDCiOpfUvzMwo")
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("SITE_NR") //Sheet name to get values
  const sites = ws.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(r => r[0] !=="").map(r => r[0])
  return sites
}
```

Can you help me to add this on my code?

Thank you for all the help.

Tried to implement some solutions provided by forums but none of them worked so far.